# What is the scope of semiconductor device fabrication compared to other fields?

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, solid-state-devices

I am planning on applying to colleges for pursuing an MS degree. I would like to know the scope of semiconductor device modelling, both in terms of jobs as well as research. I also wish to know about any current trends, popular subfields in semiconductor device modelling.

Comment: please edit your question to include "Device modeling"

Comment: I would consult with PEng association in your locale for a salary survey and to get some  idea of job market, then follow your passion.  If you were in Toronto area then AMD might be a good site to see what jobs are offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that is a very specialized field with probably not that many jobs globally. It's almost as specialized as, say, writing video chip graphics drivers.

However, there are related fields which are very active at present, most notably in 2D physics eg graphene, molybdenum disulfide, topological conductors semiconductors insulators etc with an eye to future electonics devices ranging from transistor related, to sensors.